# RewriteRules in .htaccess not redirecting for Drupal Website on cPanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7, cpanel

Consider the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.5
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=user
RewriteRule .* /denied/from/this/ip [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user
RewriteRule .* /denied/from/this/ip [F,L]
```

This is a htaccess file on a cPanel system running Ubuntu, Apache 2.4.41 and is on a PHP/Drupal based system. The script is basically saying, if you access /user or a user the query string above and you're not using one of those IP addresses, then you're forbidden.

On my standalone Ubuntu system, both of these work flawlessly and we get a standard "Forbidden" page. Within cPanel however, the first chunk of rules using QUERY_STRING goes back to the home page, while the second chunk of rules simply carries on and loads up the user "folder".

Im at a loss to explain the difference in the two behaviours.

If I tag an R=302 onto the end of the RewriteRule flags, then I get caught in a cycle of Apache telling me that the page has been moved, click "here", where here takes me back to "/user".

So I know the RewriteCond's are matching, and certainly, we get 403's in the apache access log. It is almost like it's ignoring the RewriteRule redirection or ignoring the forbidden flag, or both.

Comment: Not sure if the combination of rewriting to a different URL, and the `F` flag, makes that much sense? The manual uses `-` for no substitution in its example, and says that if you want to respond with a 403 forbidden, then there was “no reason” to redirect anywhere else at the same time. Not sure that means it is technically impossible though.

Comment: Im sort of with you on that one - without the "R" on the flags, the above code doesn't work - either with a path, or with a "-". It is the strangest issue I've seen.